# My single-key hotkey in VS doesn't work; "Waiting for additional keypress"

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, visual-studio-2008

I set the `File.Close` command in Visual Studio 2008 to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, but when I press this key it simply says “(Ctrl+W) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord.” in the status bar. If I press it again, “The key command (Ctrl+W, Ctrl+W) is not a recognized command.” is displayed.

If I actually assign (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) to the command, the file closes as expected. Which I guess is better than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, but it's still annoying having to double-tap what is the normal "close tab" key command in almost every single application.

I remember fighting this with my last job using VS2010 but i eventually got it to work. New job, can't seem to get it working for VS2008 now :(

Comment: Did you check for other shortcuts with Ctrl-W?

Comment: If there was another shortcut assigned Ctrl+W, then shouldn't that command fire off when I press it? Or does VS not de-assign that hotkey from the *other* command and then just gets confused when I press it and instead do nothing. But no, singular Ctrl+W doesn't seem to be assigned to anything.

Comment: I meant shortcuts involving more than one combo, starting with Ctrl-W.

Comment: @DanielB So I'd have to go and clear everything that starts with Ctrl+W? Microsoft.....